# Publishing Webservice looses file (reference), locally it works

Tags: c#, web-services, dll, msbuild

I have a project which includes a webService W, a core project C, a plugin P and a thirdparty tool T from nuget. P references C and T.

In the webservice C and P are referenced. If I publish the webservice and try to use it in an Iis 7 I get a FileNotFoundException (File or on of its dependencies not found. Module not found.) for T, despite the T.dll being in the same folder as all other dlls. Same if I also reference T or just T and not P.

If I loose both the references to P and T, Service compiles and works (but obvoiusly not for the intended task).

I also tried the latter and adding P.dll and T.dll manually to the folder to no avail.

If I start the WebService from VS all works as expected.

I have no clue where to look for further information or what to try next. Please give me a hint.

**Edit**
The Exact errormessage is as follows:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Die Datei oder Assembly "TTT.dll" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Die Datei oder Assembly "TTT.dll" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +92
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531

[HttpException (0x80004005): Die Datei oder Assembly "TTT.dll" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9946132
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the third party tool (T) needed the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages.